# How to load a full-size image by clicking on Thumbnail inside a RecyclerView in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, thumbnails, android-glide

I am developing an application in Android on Kotlin, where I have to show multiple thumbnails in a recycler view. On click of the specific thumbnail. I have to show the full resolution image. I am using Glide Library to load images in a recycler view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://github.com/igreenwood/loupe) library.

This library use Master/Flow detail. Your MasterActivity will be your recycler adapter and you are going to create DetailActivity to show full-size. For more please go through the library page.